# Por que me aparece excepción no controlada? c#

Tags: c#

Cuando  le doy al botón sin haber ingresado valores o introduzco valores erróneos me manda la excepción que capture en el catch pero después de esta me aparece un mensaje que dice excepción no controlada.

```
try
        {
            ClssLogin objLogin = new ClssLogin(txtUsuario.Text, txtContraseña.Text, txtID.Text);
            if (tabla.Rows.Count >= 5)
            {
              throw new FormatException(MessageBox.Show("Limite alcanzado").ToString());
            }
            tabla.Rows.Add(objLogin.Tabla(tabla));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FormatException(MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido el siguiente error" + ex).ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es sumamente sencilla.

Cuando usas un bloque `try`/`catch` en `c#`, el bloque `try` hará cosas, y si en el él se genera una excepción, dejará el `try` y pasará al bloque del `catch`.

Ahora, tu problema radica en que, dentro del `catch` estás generando una nueva excepción. si lo que deseas, es simplemente mostrar el error, puedes utilizar la excepción que está generando (que tienes como parámetro en el `catch`) para mostrar el mensaje. sería algo así:

```
try{
   //algún código que explote
}catch(Excepcion ex){
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda